# Как передать переменную в путь?

Tags: python, переменные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такой путь к нужной переменной:

```
instance_table.table_data.data.08.text
```

Как сделать вместо 08 - переменную?

Например:

```
x = str(input())
print(instance_table.table_data.data.{x}.text)
```

Я правда не знаю как это сделать и уже обыскался в гугле, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Как этот "путь" используется в коде? Это строка или что?

Comment: ``instance_table.table_data.data.08.text`` - это не путь. Для начала разберись что у тебя чем является. Если словарь - то обращайся по ключу, если список, то по индексу.

Comment: Честно говоря, понятия не имел, что это был словарь, спасибо.